# Why does returning an element of a copied Matrix3d result in incorrect output when using Clang 3.9?

Tags: clang, eigen, eigen3

Compiling the following example with `-O2` on Clang 3.9 results in the reproFunction returning garbage (`1.9038e+185`) when called in `main`:

#### Code

```
double reproFunction(const Eigen::Matrix3d& R_in)
{
  const Eigen::Matrix3d R = R_in;

  Eigen::Matrix3d Q = R.cwiseAbs();

  if(R(1,2) < 2) {
    Eigen::Vector3d n{0, 1, R(1, 2)};
    double s2 = R(1,2);
    s2 /= n.norm();
  }
  return R(1, 2);
}

int main() {
  Eigen::Matrix3d R;
  R = Eigen::Matrix3d::Zero(3,3); 

  // This fails - reproFunction(R) returns 0
  R(1, 2) = 0.7;
  double R12 = reproFunction(R);
  bool are_they_equal = (R12 == R(1,2));
  std::cout << "R12 == R(1,2): " << are_they_equal << std::endl;
  std::cout << "R12: " << R12 << std::endl;
  std::cout << "R(1, 2): " << R(1, 2) << std::endl;
}
```

#### Output

```
R12 == R(1,2): 0
R12: 1.9036e+185
R(1, 2): 0.7
```

`reproFunction`, initializes `R` (*which is const*) by assignment from `R_in`. It returns `R(1, 2)`. Between the assignment and the return, `reproFunction` uses `R` in several operations, but none of them should be able to change `R`. Removing any of those operations results in `reproFunction` returning the correct value.

This behavior does not appear in any of the following cases:

- The program is compiled with Clang 3.5, Clang 4.0,or g++-5.4.
- The optimization level is `-O1` or lower
- Eigen 3.2.10 is used instead of Eigen 3.3.3

**Now the question:** Is this behavior due to a bug I've missed in the code above, a bug in Eigen 3.3.3, or a bug in Clang 3.9?

A self-contained reproduction example can be found at https://github.com/avalenzu/eigen-clang-weirdness.

Comment: This sounds a lot like a bug in clang.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is the `R12`? And how far is it from `R(1, 2)` (in [ulp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/next_float/float_distance.html))? Not that will help fix it, I was just wondering...

Comment: @AviGinsburg: I've added an output line for the value of `R12` above. It appears to be a garbage value, not 0 as I had initially mis-remembered. 

The ulp distance is ` -2.77422e+18` . The [ulp](https://github.com/avalenzu/eigen-clang-weirdness/tree/ulp) branch of the example [repo](https://github.com/avalenzu/eigen-clang-weirdness) now prints out result returned by `float_distance`

Comment: It could be related to that clang's [bug](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=27908).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could reproduce this with clang 3.9, but not with clang 3.8. I bisected the issue on Eigen's side to [this commit from 2016-05-24 21:54](https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/commits/6c2dc56):

> Bug 256: enable vectorization with unaligned loads/stores. This concerns all architectures and all sizes. This new behavior can be disabled by defining EIGEN_UNALIGNED_VECTORIZE=0

That commit enables vectorized operations on unaligned data.

I still think, this is a bug in clang, but you can work-around it by compiling with

```
-D EIGEN_UNALIGNED_VECTORIZE=0
```

Also, Eigen could be 'fixed' by automatically disabling this feature if clang 3.9 is detected as compiler.